# React Native | State does not save within Modal component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have some `TouchableOpacity` components as a child of a `Modal` that keeps track of whether or not a user clicked, displaying a checkmark if it has been clicked. However, the application does not save the `checked` state when the `Modal` goes out of focus. Is there a way to keep the state value saved somehow even while the `Modal` is not visible on the screen?

I attached the `TouchableOpacity` component below. You can assume that it lives inside the `Modal` component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import { Icon } from '@rneui/themed'
import { filtersList } from '../../util/filters'

let FilterItem = ({ filter, index }) => {
    let [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)

    return (
        <View style={(index != filtersList.length - 1) ? styles.border : styles.noBorder}>
            <TouchableOpacity 
                style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignContent: 'center' }}
                onPress={() => setChecked(!checked)}
            >
               ---misc things
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>        
    )
}

let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    --misc things
})

export default FilterItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done as the modal unmount when not focused you have you'll have to pass the checked and setChecked method to the the touchable component

Comment: What I ended up doing was having my state include a boolean that checked whether an option was clicked, and referenced it using context whenever it had to be changed.